# What's the #I equivalent for a .fsproj file?

Tags: f#

I want to convert a script to a project. In the script, I set the path to the referenced .dlls using #I. Is there a way to specify this path directly in the .fsproj file ?

Thanks

Comment: #I means IncludePath too lookup references.

Answer (score 7):

The `fsproj` file is actually an [MS Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-concepts?view=vs-2022) script, so you can use standard MS Build features to define variables (such as your include path) and use them in the project file. This is not as simple as using `#I` directive in F# script files, but it should give you similar features.

For example, you can create a file `Includes.proj` that defines your include path like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludePath>C:\MyIncludePath</IncludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you can modify the `fsproj` file to reference the above file and use `$(IncludePath)` in your references. Sadly, this has to be done in a text editor (i.e. unload the project, modify it and then reload it):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="Includes.proj" />
  <!-- lots of other stuff -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core" />
    <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
      <HintPath>$(IncludePath)\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- lots of other stuff -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set reference folders in `Project Properties` -> `Reference Paths` -> `Add Folder`.

If you want to do this programmatically, set Reference Paths under `<Project><PropertyGroup><ReferencePath>...` and set relative paths of dlls in `<Project><ItemGroup><Reference><HintPath>...`. Here is [a script](https://gist.github.com/2062683) doing in reverse (from fsproj to fsx file), but it could give you some hints to proceed.